# Error while dealing with Django UserProfile form.

Tags: django

This is my view for User registration:

```
def user_reg(request):
    UserReg = modelformset_factory(UserProfile)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = UserReg(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        formset = UserReg()
    return render_to_response("regform.html",{"formset":formset,})
```

This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    reg_no = models.TextField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception Type: DatabaseError at /register/
Exception Value: column auth_userprofile.name does not exist
LINE 1: ..._userprofile"."id", "auth_userprofile"."user_id", "auth_user...
```

I've two questions here:
1. Obviously, i want to know why I'm getting the error and how to debug.
2. Is this the right way to go about it or should a define it in forms.py and then import it? The model formset I meant. The django documentation showed that this way it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a database error, you need to add the column "name" to the table "auth_userprofile". I'd highly recommend looking into "South" for all your database schema migration needs.

Comment: Yes and No. Syncdb doesn't diff tables, it can only create them from scratch, so if you're willing to lose all the data (or export, sync, import) that's fine, but once you're live you'll want something a bit more robust.